# Standard TCP/IP over SSH and MySQL Workbench

Tags: ssh, mysql-workbench, tcp

I have just installed `MySQL Workbench` on my Mac and trying to configure the basic parameters to connect to a server.

I know the URL of the server (and its IP) as well as the port number and of course my own username and password on it.

Trying to connect with `Standard TCP/IP over SSH` I am confused as to where these details go?

What is the difference between `SSH hostname` and `MySQL hostname` in simple terms?

Could someone please help me unserstand these elementary bits; e.g. which field refers to my credentials on the server and which field to do with my Mac's SSH client and shell, etc...?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend watching my [tutorial video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DCgRF4KOYIY&list=PLWx5a9Tn2EvH0q2WXpUBqptxi5640qk9O) which explains those details and tries to help troubleshooting connection problems. Additionally, you may want to establish an ssh connection via the terminal to get the idea of how ssh works (creating an SSH tunnel to a remote host and operating from there as if it where local). Also, use SSH only if needed. If you can reach the server directly, then do so.

**Some more info about SSH work:**

The ssh host is the machine where the SSH server is running on. You always connect to an SSH server which is then creating a tunnel between itself and the client from which you connect. This tunnel  transparently forwards commands so that it appears as if you were working on the SSH host.

Now imagine you would instead sit at the remote machine. Seen from that under which address is the MySQL server reachable? This is the address you have to enter for the MySQL server in Workbench. For instance if your MySQL server would run on the same box as your SSH server it would be reachable under `localhost` (or the IPv4/IPv6 loopback address). In that case you would enter `localhost` as the MySQL server address in the connection parameters.

Hope that clarifies things.

Comment: Thanks Mike, Very informative, But I still do not understand "what is the ssh host to which we are creating a tunnel" as you say in your tutorial? I am referring to the "TCP/IP over SSH" connection method. What is the machine that is the end point of the ssh tunnel? I know there is a server in the next room on which I have an account, and I can connect to it using my Mac Terminal, by entering at the command line: ssh myusername@dev.ru.edu

Comment: It lets me in after I enter my password, and upon doing pwd, I get: /home/myusername which means I am in.